# Pass value from one component to another (siblings) in react/nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a problem trying to pass one value to a modal in another sibling component in NextJS, i know about context but it's too hard to understand for me and the structure is not done for that.

Ex (i will use one value called test):

```
//components/formulario.js
import React, { useState, Component } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import axios from 'axios';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const Formulario = () => {

    const [seleccion, setOSC] = useState();
    const organizaciones = [
            {
              label: "Seleccionar OSC",
              value: "test",
            },
    ]
return (

  <div className="selectContainer mx-auto p-5">
   <div className="input-group input-group-dynamic mb-4">
      <span className="input-group input-group-dynamic mb-4-addon"><i className="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
      <select {...register('organizations', { required: true })} id="organizations" className="form-control selectpicker" value={seleccion} onChange={selectedOSC} >
      {organizaciones.map((organizacion) => (
      <option key={organizacion.label} value={organizacion.value}>{organizacion.label}</option>
      ))}
      </select>
   </div>
</div>

)
}

export default Formulario;
```

When the user select the value (seleccion in this case "test" is the only value i have) i want it to display in the following component with a modal:

```
//components/ambiente.js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

const Ambiente = (props) => {

    return (
        <Modal>
            <Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Title>Organizaciones</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <p>{//display the selected value here}</p>
                </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary">
                Cerrar
                </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    )

}

export default Ambiente;
```

Both are siblings components, i know i can't pass from sibling1 to sibling2 but i would like to know how to this in my case because i couldn't find any fiddle/tutorial to do what i want to achieve. Thanks in advance.

PD: I tried to make the code the most simple i could so you can understand what i want. Any question you have i will post it here.

UPDATE:

Tried:

```
const sendData = () => {
    props.parentCallback("Test");
}
```

But i get:

```
TypeError: props.parentCallback is not a function
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong i changed also

```
const Formulario = () => {
```

with

```
const Formulario = (props) => {
```

but not working

I'm doing this to pass from child Formulario to App Parent.

my app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Formulario from '../components/formulario';
import Ambiente from '../components/ambiente';

const App = () => {

    state = { message: "" }
    callbackFunction = (childData) => {
      this.setState({message: childData})
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <Formulario parentCallback={this.callbackFunction} /> 
            <Ambiente dataFromParent={this.state.data} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Tried everything, can anyone help me please?

Comment: You can use these states in the parent component and pass the state through props. If you can't able to implement it on your own let me know I will provide you an example code

Comment: I will try something like that and post it here. Thanks!

Comment: Updated with latest things i tried but cannot make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You mess both class-based and functional component

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import Formulario from '../components/formulario';
import Ambiente from '../components/ambiente';

const App = () => {

const [message,setMessage]=useState("");
const callbackFunction= (event) =>setMessage(event.currentTarget.value);


return (
    <div>
        <Formulario parentCallback={callbackFunction} /> 
        <Ambiente dataFromParent={message} />
    </div>
 )
}

export default App;
```

formulario

```
import React, { useState, Component } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import axios from 'axios';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const Formulario = (props) => {

  const organizaciones = [
        {
          label: "Seleccionar OSC",
          value: "test",
        },
   ]
 return (

  <div className="selectContainer mx-auto p-5">
    <div className="input-group input-group-dynamic mb-4">
     <span className="input-group input-group-dynamic mb-4-addon"><i 
       className="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>

 //i Don't know why you use onChange on select their are other purpose to 
 use on change let me know in comment below

     <select {...register('organizations', { required: true })} 
     id="organizations" className="form-control selectpicker" onClick= 
     {props.parentCallback} >
    {organizaciones.map((organizacion) => (
    <option key={organizacion.label} value={organizacion.value}> 
   {organizacion.label}</option>
   ))}
    </select>
  </div>
 </div>

  )
}

export default Formulario;
```

components/ambiente.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

const Ambiente = (props) => {

  return (
    <Modal>
        <Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Title>Organizaciones</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                <p>{props.dataFromParent}</p>
            </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
            <Button variant="secondary">
            Cerrar
            </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
)
```

}

export default Ambiente;

Comment: I tried that solution and other ones but cannot make it work... :(

Comment: Edited: Worked after import App.js into my index.js page. I will test more and send my feedback, Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure bro make sure you read the error always don't be panic if an error caught you should read the error and analyze your code if you still get stuck then ask for help with the error code  also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to lift your state up to the nearest parent of the components.